# Mongoose unique index for ObjectId field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

Trying to create unique index for an ObjectId field.
I tried:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    field: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SomeModel',
        unique: true,
    } });
```

and...

```
var schema = new Schema({
    field: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SomeModel',
        index: {unique: true}
} });
```

I can't get it working and it seems a very common problem.

Comment: `Schema.Types.ObjectId`? Or what error are you getting?

Comment: i didnt understand what do you want? please make your question more clear.

Comment: @jackblank oops. intersting, still works for population... but not for uniqueness. fixed and working. thanks!

Comment: @RaviShankar the question is solved. I wanted to have only one field id per document on that collection. uniqueness by field.

Comment: actually, if you look at `mongoose.Schema`, you will find that it has `ObjectId` as well, so `Schema.ObjectId` and `Schema.Types.Objectid`, anyone should have worked.

Comment: @RaviShankar it didn't and I was using a custom validation path for checking uniqueness. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was a typo at the `type` definition, dumb of me...

The type should be:

```
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

as jack black noted. I didn't noticed the typo because my code definition still worked for query population. strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`Schema.Types.ObjectId` instead of `Schema.ObjectId`